# Removing horizontal scroll on mobile site

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview, responsiveness

I'm having some issues with horizontal scroll on the mobile version of a website I am building. I have tried adding overflow-x:hidden to no avail. The only thing that seems to do anything at all is this:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
             box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But instead of fixing the problem, it shifts everything over to the left where it gets cut off on both desktop and mobile. My media queries don't seem to be working either. Can anyone help please?